# Removing all hlines in xtable generated longtables

Tags: longtable, r, knitr, xtable

Even by setting `hline.after = NULL`, a longtable generated by the R package `xtable` still mantains an hline at the very end of the table.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

<<results='asis'>>=
require(xtable)
print(xtable(cars[1:20,], caption = 'NO HLINES'), 
      tabular.environment = "longtable", include.rownames = F, 
      caption.placement = "top", include.colnames = FALSE, 
      hline.after = NULL, floating = FALSE)
@

\end{document}
```

results in

```
\begin{longtable}{rr}
\caption{NO HLINES} \\ 
  4.00 & 2.00 \\ 
  4.00 & 10.00 \\ 
  7.00 & 4.00 \\ 
  7.00 & 22.00 \\ 
  8.00 & 16.00 \\ 
  9.00 & 10.00 \\ 
  10.00 & 18.00 \\ 
  10.00 & 26.00 \\ 
  10.00 & 34.00 \\ 
  11.00 & 17.00 \\ 
  11.00 & 28.00 \\ 
  12.00 & 14.00 \\ 
  12.00 & 20.00 \\ 
  12.00 & 24.00 \\ 
  12.00 & 28.00 \\ 
  13.00 & 26.00 \\ 
  13.00 & 34.00 \\ 
  13.00 & 34.00 \\ 
  13.00 & 46.00 \\ 
  14.00 & 26.00 \\ 
  \hline
\end{longtable}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add the argument `booktabs=TRUE` in the print.xtable call

```
print(xtable(cars[1:20,], caption = 'NO HLINES'), 
  tabular.environment = "longtable", include.rownames = F, 
  caption.placement = "top", include.colnames = FALSE, 
  booktabs = TRUE,
  hline.after = NULL, floating = FALSE)
```

results:

```
\begin{longtable}{rr}
\caption{NO HLINES} \\ 
4.00 & 2.00 \\ 
4.00 & 10.00 \\ 
7.00 & 4.00 \\ 
7.00 & 22.00 \\ 
8.00 & 16.00 \\ 
9.00 & 10.00 \\ 
10.00 & 18.00 \\ 
10.00 & 26.00 \\ 
10.00 & 34.00 \\ 
11.00 & 17.00 \\ 
11.00 & 28.00 \\ 
12.00 & 14.00 \\ 
12.00 & 20.00 \\ 
12.00 & 24.00 \\ 
12.00 & 28.00 \\ 
13.00 & 26.00 \\ 
13.00 & 34.00 \\ 
13.00 & 34.00 \\ 
13.00 & 46.00 \\ 
14.00 & 26.00 \\ 
\end{longtable}
```